# Why $limit in mongoose with aggregation not return all results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've following `aggregation` query, which has `$limit` I've set it's working fine if I pass a number between `1 to any` positive integer. Now, I need all results than I pass `limit: 0` So, it's through me ERROR.

> Assert: command failed: {
>       "ok" : 0,
>       "errmsg" : "the limit must be positive",
>       "code" : 15958,
>       "codeName" : "Location15958"
>     } : aggregate failed

Query

```
var limit = 0; // working with 1 to infinite ( any positive integrer ) 
db.getCollection('abc').aggregate([
    {
        $match : {}
    },
    {
        $limit: limit
    }
])
```

Let me come out of this If anyone knows how should I return all documents from a database with `$limit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build up your pipeline to only include the `$limit` element when it's needed:

```
var pipeline = [{$match: {}}];
if (limit) {
    pipeline.push({$limit: limit});
}
db.getCollection('abc').aggregate(pipeline);
```